# curl with awk get last line fails

Tags: curl, awk

I have the following curl + awk command which works as long as the data is only 4 lines, however, the number of lines can change and I'm stuck at this point.  Essentially the curl + awk should ONLY grab the last line which always ends in an equal sign (=), and within that line the first 3 digits of the second grouping of numbers.

```
curl "http://www.nws.noaa.gov/view/validProds.php?prod=TAF&node=KOKX" |grep --after-context=2 "KLGA " |head -3 |tail -1 |awk '{print substr($2,0,4)}'
```

Comment: Post a sample input and expected output..

Answer (score 1):

If I have interpreted your requirements correctly, this does what you want.  This selects the first line that follows "KLGA" that ends with an equal sign.  For that line, it prints the first three characters of the second field:

```
curl -s "http://www.nws.noaa.gov/view/validProds.php?prod=TAF&node=KOKX" | awk '/KLGA/{f=1} f && /=$/ {print substr($2,1,3);exit}'
```

#### How it works

The output of curl is fed to this `awk` command:

```
awk '/KLGA/{f=1} f && /=$/ {print substr($2,1,3);exit}'
```

Taking each step, one at a time:

- `/KLGA/{f=1}`

  This looks for a line containing "KLGA" and sets the flag `f` to `1`.
- `f && /=$/ {print substr($2,1,3);exit}`

  If the flag `f` is nonzero and this line ends with an equal sign, then these two commands are executed:

  1. `print substr($2,1,3)`

     This prints the first three characters of the second field.
  2. `exit`

     Because we are ignoring the rest of the file, this exits `awk`.

In summary, the code looks for a line containing `KLGA`.  Once it has found that line, signaled by setting `f==1`, it looks for the first line that ends with an equal sign.  One that line, it extracts the first three characters from the second field and prints them.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  But I'm getting an error when I run that. curl: (23) Failed writing body (363 != 1356)    Check out the format of the page: [link](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/view/validProds.php?prod=TAF&node=KOKX)

Comment: @jeffschips "I'm getting an error"  Computers work on specifics.  Precisely what error did you receive?  I just copied the command from the answer here, pasted it to the command line: it downloaded from NASA and parsed the output without error.  If you are getting an error, you need to tell me what it is.

Comment: I stand corrected!  It captures the data fine if I pipe it into a file with > into_a_file.txt.  However it just get's messy when printing to the screen. . . dunno why.  The error I received was inlcuded in my comment above: curl: (23) Failed writing body (363 != 1356).  But as I followed up with, it only produces that error on the screen, not if I pipe into a file, which is actually what I needed.

Comment: `curl` likes to display a progress bar.  Is that what you mean by "messy"?  If so, add the `-s` option to `curl` to silence it.

Comment: So I'm trying to understand the flow: What does setting a flag to 1 accomplish?  If done in this way, does that mean the logic flows until the equal sign and the substr goes backwards to extract the data?  Thank you

Comment: @jeffschips Because of `f`, it doesn't start looking for the equal sign until after it first sees `KLGA`.  Once it has seen `KLGA`, it looks for the first line that after that that ends with an equal sign and extracts the the three characters from that line's second field.  That is what you want, isn't it?